# Can't push to remote docker registry

Tags: docker

When trying to push an image to a remote docker registry i get the message:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/helloworld$ docker push 11.22.33.44:5000/ltrojanowski/helloworld
The push refers to a repository [11.22.33.44:5000/ltrojanowski/helloworld]
unable to ping registry endpoint https://11.22.33.44:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://11.22.33.44:5000/v2/: EOF
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://11.22.33.44:5000/v1/_ping: EOF
```

This is despite changing the etc/default/docker on the server to look like:

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

#
# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD
#
#   Please see the documentation for "systemd drop-ins":
#   https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/
#

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 11.22.33.44:5000"
# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

I only added the `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 11.22.33.44:5000"` line, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/).
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: By "on the server" do you mean on the machine that's pushing? Or the registry machine? I think this setting belongs on the machine from which you're trying to push.

Comment: @AssafLavie Thanks for your help, your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I misunderstood the instruction. One needs to add the line `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 11.22.33.44:5000"` in the machine which is pushing the container, and not the registry machine.

Comment: in my case I cannot write into the `etc/default/docker` saying read-only file, i cannot change its permission too!
what should I do now!!@lukasz